# Unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init, cannot start any app

Tags: sdl, external, symbols

My simple code in VS2012:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SDL.h>
#undef main
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

returns following errors:

```
1>ConsoleApplication21.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _main
1>ConsoleApplication21.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function _main
```

I have linked proper folders in project properties, added SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib to dependences, I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: How are you adding SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib?  Select Project Properties/Linker/Command Line.  Are the libraries in quotes or not.  If they are in quotes, you're missing the line separator in the dependencies.  Click on the ellipsis and separate the libraries with a newline.

Comment: They were separated with a newline from the very beginning. So it's fine. Also, when I try to link the invalid for my system (x86) libraries, there are no linking errors, but program exits immidiately with code 0xc000007b. I run x64 Windows 8.

Comment: If you have x86 libraries, build it as x86 or win32.

Comment: I do not understand. Should I use x86 libraries even though my system is x64? Additionally, which type of project should I use then? Currently I was using Win32 Console Application.

Comment: You can run x86 on an x64 OS.  If your libraries are x86 then you should build as x86/win32.  If your libraries are x64 then build as x64.